# Why some fields will not show a red boarder when they have model erros

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I am working on an asp.net mvc 5 web application. And I have the following inside my edit/create view , to show two fields named `ILIOP` & `Comment`:

```
<div>
    <span class="f">  @Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Server.ILOIP)</span>
    @Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
</div>

<div>
    <span class="f">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model=>model.Server.Comment)</span>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(model=>model.Server.Comment,new { @class = "textArea"})

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model =>model.Server.Comment)
</div>
```

Now on my Post Edit action method I am checking for concurrency conflicts errors and display an error message beside the related fields:

```
if (databaseValues.ILOIP != clientValues.ILOIP)
    ModelState.AddModelError("Server.ILOIP", "Current value: " + databaseValues.ILOIP);

 if (databaseValues.Comment != clientValues.Comment)
     ModelState.AddModelError("Server.Comment", " Current Value: " + databaseValues.Comment);
```

Now if there are error on those two fields (ILIOP & Comment) , then the comment field will get a red boarder around it, while the ILIOP will not , as follow:-

[image]

now here is the markup when the view is first rendered for  the 2 fields (without errors):

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
       data-val-length="The field ILOIP must be a string with a maximum length of 20." 
       data-val-length-max="20" id="Server_ILOIP" name="Server.ILOIP" 
       type="text" value="4" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Server.ILOIP" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

<textarea class="textArea" cols="20" data-val="true" 
          data-val-length="The field Comment must be a string with a maximum length of 256." 
          data-val-length-max="256" id="Server_Comment" 
          name="Server.Comment" rows="2">
</textarea>
```

and here is the markup when errors are displayed for the two fields :-

```
 <input class="input-validation-error text-box single-line" data-val="true" 
        data-val-length="The field ILOIP must be a string with a maximum length of 20." 
        data-val-length-max="20" id="Server_ILOIP" name="Server.ILOIP" 
        type="text" value="4" />
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Server.ILOIP" 
      data-valmsg-replace="true">Current value: 3</span>

<textarea class="input-validation-error textArea" cols="20" data-val="true" 
          data-val-length="The field Comment must be a string with a maximum length of 256." 
          data-val-length-max="256" id="Server_Comment" 
          name="Server.Comment" rows="2">
</textarea>

<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="Server.Comment" data-valmsg-replace="true"> Current Value: 3</span>
```

So can anyone advice what is the reason that the ILIOP field does not show a red boarder around it when it has an error associated with it, while the comment field will show a red border  ?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your CSS for the page is defined in such a way that the textarea element is getting the red styling when both class input-validation-error and class textArea are on the element.

As an initial test of my hypothesis, see what happens if you change

```
@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP)
```

to

```
@Html.EditorFor(model =>model.Server.ILOIP, new { @class = "textArea"})
```

and retry your test case with this change.  You may have to rebuild your source code and clear your browser's cache after making this change.